# How can I get the url friendly with Yii or htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, yii, friendly-url

Can you help me to obtain the rewrite rule from the htaccess or the rule form the Yii urlManager

I have this url:

http://www.exmple.com/site/busqueda?subcategoria=Ahoyadora+de+tierras&long=&lat=

And I would like:

http://www.exmple.com/busqueda/Ahoyadora+de+tierras

Thanks in advance,

Toni

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In UrlManager config:

```
'rules' => array(
    'busqueda/<subcategoria>' => 'site/busqueda',
    // ... other rules below
```

In controller SiteController.php:

```
public action busquedaAction($subcategoria) {

    // do something
    var_dump($subcategoria);

    // render view
}
```

OR, you can try this .htaccess rules

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule busqueda/(.+) site/busqueda?subcategoria=$1
```